# C# Email parsing. Error: The program ... has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Tags: c#, email, mimekit

I develop simple application for renaming locally stored emails. Emails are loaded in a listbox and there is a button which does renaming. The problem is that I can rename three email and than the application crushes. No specific error reported. Here is my code...

```
namespace EmailFilenameRename
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    CultureInfo deCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static string[] getAddressParts(string address)
    {
        var splittedAdress = address.Split(' ');
        return splittedAdress.Last().Trim().StartsWith("<")
            ? new[] { string.Join(" ", splittedAdress.Take(splittedAdress.Length - 1)), splittedAdress.Last().Trim(' ', '<', '>') }
            : splittedAdress;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\...\in");
        FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.eml");
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        string oldName = @"C:\...\in\" + listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);

        var mail = Sasa.Net.Mail.Message.Parse(File.ReadAllText(oldName));

        string dt = mail.Headers["Date"].ToString();

        DateTimeOffset originalTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse(dt, deCulture);
        DateTime utcTime = originalTime.UtcDateTime.ToLocalTime();

        string sTime = utcTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd HHmm");

        string[] sFrom = getAddressParts(mail.From.ToString());
        string sSubject = mail.Subject.Replace(":", "");

        String newName = @"C:\...\in\renamed\" + sTime + " -- " + sFrom[1] + " -- " + sSubject + ".eml";

        File.Copy(oldName, newName);
        File.Delete(oldName);
    }
}
```

}

I have also tried with MimeKit... the same problem exists.

Comment: Exit code 0 is a success...do you get an exception?

Comment: No. Application just closes.

Comment: Anything in the Visual Studio "Output" window?

Comment: This exception: Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in mscorlib.dll

Comment: OK it seems that you have disabled some of the standard exceptions. Press Ctrl+Alt+E to open the exceptions window, and maybe reset it to the default exceptions (so execution will break on things like this). It's probably something to do with "..." in the paths. If you can get the full exception and edit it into your question, we can go from there.

Comment: I've replaced my path with "..." and I've restored Exception Settings. All the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196843/discussion-between-arnes-and-john).